# bootstrap-table: th - add on the left an icon

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-table

anyone has an idea how to add something to the left in the bootstrap-table header? Like on the picture below I want to add an icon (question mark or whatever) to be a clickable link.

[image]

[jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/27/)

```
<table id="summaryTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-width="20px" >id</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="type" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm still checking if it's enough to work with my code I need and if I'm not having more questions to your answer. It seems to be the answer I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an element to every `th`:

```
  $('#summaryTable thead th').each(function() {
    s = $('<span style="position: absolute; left: 4px; top: 8px; cursor: pointer;">?</span>')
    s.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Question mark clicked')
    });
    $(this).append(s)
  })
```

> Note the `e.stopPropagation();` to make sure the clicks on the question mark will not cause also a click on the entire `TH`

Here is a fork of your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dekelb/e403uvuh/

Comment: I found a side effect of `position: relative;` [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e403uvuh/1/). If I add it then header's cell border is gone. Also the question marks aren't in the same line with text. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Just set the correct `top` value. I set it to `12px`, in your example you would probably want `4px`

Comment: Look at the updated jsFiddle link in my first comment. I'd need different `top` for different header cells. I modified my example because your code (which is very close to what I need) gives me bad side effects.

Comment: If you have different positioning of the content of your `th` - you will also need different positioning of the `?` char (because we used **absolute** position).

Comment: everything about the css is here [jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e403uvuh/1/) but I have no idea how it should be fixed.

Comment: You didn't change the `top` value... start with that.

Comment: but this not the matter of changing the `top`. I changed [jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e403uvuh/2/) and now the column ID is not correct.

Comment: Which is **exactly** what I wrote in the previous comment. You can't "have it all" :) Anther option is to use the `top` positioned in the CSS (and not inline).

Comment: I've fixed the `top` for different `th` cells [jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e403uvuh/3/) but I still can't fix the disappearing border when adding `position: relative` for `th`

Comment: what disappearing border?

Comment: Please comment `position: relative` in `#summaryTable th {}` and you will see the difference. I'm stack with this and I can't go farther. I don't know why is this happening, what I'm doing wrong in css section.

Comment: Already have and I don't see any difference. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using FF, but now I found that on Chrome is fine, so it is just FF problem so far. Try on FF.

Comment: Changed the `div` to be the relatively positioned and added the question mark to that div: https://jsfiddle.net/0nurtm14/

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be better than the first version :) (one `top` to all) I'll do some more testing and be back later.